# how researchers extract encryption times when randomness is involved?

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves

I have seen some research papers where they compare encryption/signature times on elliptic curves.But when i have implemented the algorithms and calculated encryption times but each time i get some different timing.i thought this was due to random scalar chosen for scalar multiplication in el-gamal encryption scheme.So do researchers take average or min or max of the values they obtain?How do they get those execution times when randomness is involved?

Comment: There should be sections in the research where they describe the hardware or demonstrate the time complexity.  If they are discussing implementations, the difference you see is hardware related.  For time complexity formalism, these can be worst case, average case, or best case depending on context.  Hope this helps.